# WordPress External DB Authentication

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress, external

I have 2 different websites. One is the Wordpress site and the other a oldish asp.net site.

I want to log in on the wordpress site OR the ASP.NET site and be logged in on both sites. Also, I want to have a link to the ASP.NET site from the wordpress site.

I.E. I'll log in on the Wordpress site using ASP.Net user account. (Only admin accounts should see these buttons) Once logged in, I'd click on the Manage Users link that will take me to another page (Asp.net, this could be the same domain or another location), And here I'll be able to make CRUD changes to the Users.

My php knowledge is very limited >.< ...

I've looked at these Wordpress plugins but both seem outdated and unable to run.  I am also un-sure whether they would do what I want.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-db-auth-reloaded/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-database-access-using-wp-user/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this is helpful.. but you can access SQL Server Database with PHP.

**Loading the Driver**
You can download the SQL Server Driver for PHP at the Microsoft Download Center. Included in the download are two .dll files: php_sqlsrv.dll and php_sqlsrv_ts.dll.

**Configuring the Driver**
The SQL Server Driver for PHP has three configuration options:

- LogSubsystems:
  Use this option to turn the logging of subsystems on or off. The default setting is SQLSRV_LOG_SYSTEM_OFF (logging is turned off by default).
- LogSeverity:
  Use this option to specify what to log after logging has been turned on. The default setting is SQLSRV_LOG_SEVERITY_ERROR (only errors are logged by default after logging has been turned on).
- WarningsReturnAsErrors:
  By default, the SQL Server Driver for PHP treats warnings generated by sqlsrv functions as errors. Use the WarningsReturnAsErrors option to change this behavior. The default setting for this option is true.

**Creating a Connection**
The sqlsrv_connect function is used to establish a connection to the server.

```
$serverName = "(local)";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"DBNAME");

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);
if( $conn === false )
{ die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
```

By default, the sqlsrv_connect function uses Windows Authentication to establish a connection.

The sqlsrv_connect function accepts two parameters: $serverName and $connectionOptions (optional).

- $serverName – This required parameter is used to specify the name of the server to which you want to connect. In the code above, a connection is established to the local server. This parameter can also be use to specify a SQL Server instance or a port number.

For example:
$serverName = "myServer\instanceName";
-or-
$serverName = "myServer, 1521";

- $connectionOptions - This optional parameter is an array of key-value pairs that set options on the connection. In the code above, the database is set to DBNAME for the connection. Other options include ConnectionPooling, Encrypt, UID, and PWD.

Note:   The UID and PWD options must be set in the $connectionOptions parameter to log into the server with SQL Server Authentication.

Go through below link for more details:

[Accessing SQL Server Databases with PHP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: @xFrenzy47x can you please review my answer and let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Apologies. Your answer seems viable however I'm unable to find the download links on Microsoft site to implement the above. The resources might be outdated.

Comment: Sorry, I believe they archived it somewhere later I posted my answer. Can you please try below download link and try to implement the above.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683517(v=sql.105).aspx

Thanks!